# How to apply custom transition animation in UINavigationControllerDelegate to specific push and pop events?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom animation transition for push and pop events in a UINavigationController stack and I want to apply that custom animation only to specific push events--for example, when pushing RandomViewController44() or popping RandomViewController27()--not every push and pop in the stack. Is that done in the UINavigationControllerDelegate, in the animator object, or at the point of push/pop?

**The delegate**

```
extension BaseViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch operation {
        case .push:
            return InAnimator()
        case .pop:
            return OutAnimator()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

**The animator object**

```
class InAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let animationDuration = 0.5

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return animationDuration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)

        containerView.addSubview(toViewController!.view)

        toViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth * -1, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
            toViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        }, completion: { finished in
            let cancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!cancelled)
        })

    }

}
```

**The call to push**

```
func pushVC() {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(randomViewController44(), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Check the fromView and ToView controller in below delegate method for perform action

```
extension BaseViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch operation {
        case .push:
            if toVc is RandomViewController44{
               return InAnimator()
            }
            return nil
        case .pop:
            if RandomViewController27 is fromVC{
              return OutAnimator()
            }
            return nil
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

You need to check from and toView controller when this method called as set condition as per your requirement